# const arrays javascript assigning a variable value

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I set const value for arrays, I can change it later. why is there such a thing (google translate) Shouldn't the value I assign const throw an error?

```
const values=['a','b','c'];
values[0]='aaa';
console.log(values[0]);
```

Comment: const cannot be reassign const values, but we can modify the value at specific indexes or keys

Comment: Try doing only `values = something` , you will see that it throws an error

Comment: You can't assign another array to the variable `values` but `const` does nothing to prevent it's value from being changed. How can it? You could assign a shared reference to a const variable and assign it somewhere else

Comment: You can use `Object.freeze()` to prevent modifications of the array itself. Again it will apply only to the array not it's elements, which can still be modified.

Comment: @FaizalHussain No, assigning to a element of a frozen array will be ignored silently

Comment: @FaizalHussain "*freeze will prevent push and pop , but still can be modified by arr[0] = 9*" [No, that is incorrect.](https://jsbin.com/rumogik/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: yes , it just doesn't throw any errors